# vmmem is using a lot of RAM with Win10

Tags: performance, windows-10

vmmem, supposedly something to do with virtual machines, uses 1.5 GB of RAM even though no VM is active in Hyper-V. I do run docker though. The vmmem is also run as a user with a username which looks something like E076D8C-04EC-...

Is this expected behavior or is there some way I can troubleshoot it?

Edit: I shut down the Docker Desktop and then the vmmem is not there anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docker is a type of virtual machine, and if it is running, it will use memory like any virtual machine in any virtualizer.

"Proof"  You shut down Docker (the machine) and the memory is released.  This, too, is completely normal.

All is well.

Comment: in my case when I shut down Docker and its service the process is still there and the memory is not released... I can't kill it as Windows says Access Denied when I try to... Still trying to figure why it's there and how I can stop it...

Comment: When you are done with Docker , open Power Shell as Administrator and run:   cmd wsl --shutdown  .   That should release the memory.

Comment: it does indeed, but when I used that command last time then for some reason I couldn't start WSL again, and rebooting was the only thing that worked. But I'll give it another try and see how it goes...

Answer (score 2):

See [How to Stop WSL2 from Hogging All Your Ram With Docker](https://medium.com/@lewwybogus/how-to-stop-wsl2-from-hogging-all-your-ram-with-docker-d7846b9c5b37)

It suggests that you create the following text file at:

```
C:\Users\<your-username>\.wslconfig
```

```
[wsl2]
memory=4GB # Limits VM memory in WSL 2 to 4 GB
processors=2 # Makes the WSL 2 VM use two virtual processors
```

It allows you to limit the amount of RAM used by vmmem.

Answer (score 0):

For first try so:

```
wsl --shutdown
```